# Will SaveSetting always work regardless of security restrictions?

Tags: vba

I am developing a VBA application, and would like to save information like what data file was last imported to the application.  I am assuming the registry is as good a place as any to store this, but I'm concerned about deploying the solution, whether or not any IT policy would ever prevent VBA's SaveSetting function from working.

So my question is, will SaveSetting/GetSetting always work in VBA, or would there be some way that a user's IT/security policy would restrict those functions from working?

Comment: Since VBA is not supporting [exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kz7fyks(v=vs.90).aspx) what you can do is create a check registry function after execution of SaveSetting to make sure an entry has been created. I can't think of any other way to handle that.